# Page exists but is 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: 2013, page-not-found

I created a link for a new page in my SharePoint 2013 subsite using double brackets. When I click on the link, I get the 404 Page Not Found error. It does not ask me if I want to create a new page.  I suspect that at some point, I clicked my link and it asked me if I wanted to create a new page and I said OK, but never followed through.  If I go to my link and add a letter (creating a new link) it works perfectly, asking me to create a new page. 
I tried to check-in/check-out, delete the created link and create again, then it tells me it already exists. So, my pages exists but is not found.

How do I find the page that I sort-of created a few days ago?  I have only been using SharePoint for a couple of weeks, so I am really lost.

Here is a link to notes about my problem:

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s72/sh/074d5250-b4bf-4258-9192-5f3a993b8912/3da339c64fe07ab7c6a6b75f39637178

Comment: Have you checked the recycle bin? Perhaps it's preventing you from creating a new one in case someone tries to restore the deleted version.

Comment: If you have admin rights. Check under the DocLib settings for pages with no checked in versions. (Manage files which have no checked in version)

Answer (score 1):

One day I had something similar in SharePoint 2010.

Just **Check-In** your page near "Save" button.